# Signals and Slots in qt5.7 - QWebEnginePage

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have trouble in connecting `QWebEnginePage` to `fullScreenRequested` , I am trying in the following way ant it gives the error

> main.cpp:58: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
>   connect(this->view->page(), SIGNAL(fullScreenRequested(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest)), &QWebEngineFullScreenRequest, SLOT(&QWebEngineFullScreenRequest::accept()));

My Code:

```
class WebView:public QObject{
public:
    char* home_page;
    QWebEngineView* view=new QWebEngineView();
    WebView(char* page=(char*)"https://google.com"){
        this->home_page=page;
        createWebView();
        this->view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled,true);
        connect(this->view->page(),SIGNAL(fullScreenRequested(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest)),&QWebEngineFullScreenRequest,SLOT(&QWebEngineFullScreenRequest::accept()));
    }
    void createWebView(){
        this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
    }
    QWebEngineView* returnView(){
        return this->view;
    }
    void home(){
        this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
    }
};
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that signal/slot connection takes a source object, as well as a destination object as parameters, and you mixed the 2 ways of connecting.

It either

```
connect(&src, &FirstClass::signalName, &dest, &SecondClass::slotName);
```

Or

```
connect(&src, SIGNAL(signalName(argType)), &dest, SLOT(slotName(artType)));
```

In your case `&QWebEngineFullScreenRequest` is not an object, instead you are trying to take the address of a class. You need an instance of `QWebEngineFullScreenRequest` class to connect to it.

Correct way:

```
    WebView(...)
    {
        //...
        connect(this->view->page(), &QWebEnginePage::fullScreenRequested, this, &WebView::acceptFullScreenRequest);
    }

private slots:
    void acceptFullScreenRequest(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest request) {
        request.accept();
    }
```

A few other remarks:

- Try to separate class declaration in a header (.h), from the definition (.cpp) file.
- Instead of `char* page=(char*)"https://google.com"`, its better for literals to use `const char*`, or even better QString as you are using Qt
- `QWebEngineView* view=new QWebEngineView();` would be better to instantiate it inside your `WebView` constructor
- `this->` is unecessary

---

```
WebView(QObject* parent = nullptr, QString page = "https://google.com"):
    QObject(parent),
    home_page(page),
    view(new QWebEngineView())
{
//...
}
```